# Schedule a console command in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am super confused about Laravel's `commands` vs. `console commands` and which one I'm supposed to use with the task scheduler.

I am attempting to use a `console` since that's the one that seems to work with the task scheduler per Laravel's docs but for some reason it doesn't allow me to have any other methods in the command file other than the `construct`, `fire`, `getArguments`, and `getOptions`. I can't put everything in the `fire` method as it would be one big mess.

Basically I am trying to have a crawler run every 5 minutes. So other methods deal with various parts of the crawling process.

And then in the `fire` method, I'm trying to call my main method via `$this->run();` but it returns error:

`Declaration of App\Console\Commands\Crawler::run() should be compatible with Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output)`

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Just rename your run() method to anything else. As you can see from the error - this method name is already taken (by one of your parent classes) and is required by an interface

Comment: Ahh that is it.  Thank you so much!